# Transformar factor em numerico R

Tags: r, factors

Estou realizando um trabalho onde importo uma base e apos a importação eu crio uma faixa de valores.

Ex. importo a base com o `read.csv`

```
dados <- read.csv(base, header=TRUE, sep=',')
```

Porem nesta coluna de valores($$), que utilizarei para criar a faixa, na hora de importar altera para `factor`.
Diante disso utilizo o seguinte código para transformação.

```
dados$valores <- is.numeric(dados$valores)
```

O que acontece aqui é que os valores da coluna alteram todos.

Ex na coluna valor 100, ele vira 2600.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este problema é bastante frequente quando se trabalha com objetos de classe `data.frame`, que é a classe de objetos que as funções `read.table` e derivadas produzem.

Para evitar isso, basta ver que *por defeito* o valor do argumento `stringsAsFactors` é `TRUE`. Veja `help("read.csv")`, por exemplo.

Note que o `read.csv` só lê números como `factor` se esses números tiverem carateres não numéricos. Deve haver algo no ficheiro que força o R a interpretar os valores como strings. (alfanuméricas?)

A solução para não criar uma coluna de classe `factor` deverá ser

```
dados <- read.csv(base, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

(Omiti os outros argumentos porque já têm esses valores. De fato, `read.csv` é só a função `read.table` com `header = TRUE`, `sep = ","` e outros.)

Há ainda outras duas formas de transformar objetos de classe `factor` em `numeric`.

```
dados$valores <- as.numeric(as.character(dados$valores))
dados$valores <- as.numeric(levels(dados$valores))[dados$valores]
```

Da página de ajuda `help("factor")`, secção `Warning`:

> To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values,
> as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient
> than as.numeric(as.character(f)).

Tradução Google:

> Para transformar um fator f para aproximadamente seus valores numéricos originais, as.numeric(levels(f))[f] é recomendado e ligeiramente mais eficiente do que as.numeric(as.character(f)).

### Atualização - R 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)

Com o novo `R 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)` o comportamento das funções `read.*` mudou.

De [R News](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/NEWS.html), secção **CHANGES IN R 4.0.0**.

> R now uses a `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` default, and hence by default
> no longer converts strings to factors in calls to `data.frame()` and
> `read.table()`.
>
> A large number of packages relied on the previous behaviour and so
> have needed/will need updating.

Tradução Google, editada:

> O R utiliza agora `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, e portanto por defeito
> já não converte strings em factores nas chamadas a `data.frame()` e
> `read.table()`.
>
> Um grande número de pacotes baseou-se no comportamento anterior e, por
> isso, precisaram/terão de ser actualizados.

Comment: Rui, Obrigado pela ajuda e pela explicação, super esclarecido, não sabia que o read.csv lia os dados como factor, mais uma vez agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Ajustar o parâmetro stringsAsFactors = FALSE evita que os campos character sejam convertidos em factor.

Exemplo:

```
df <- read.csv("dados.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Antonio Muito Obrigado pela ajuda, refiz o código e deu certo!

Answer (score -1):

```
dados <- read.csv(base, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Modifique a função `read.csv2`

```
dados <- read.csv2(base, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```