# Problemas na categorização de uma variável numérica

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Estou usando dados do SINASC para construir tabelas de contingência no RStudio. Quero fazer uma tabela igual a do tabnet para os dados de 2018: [image: Tabela TABNET]
E fiz um código r para fazer uma tabela igual:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(read.dbc)
library(Hmisc)


DNRJ_2018 <- read.dbc(file.choose())
tb2018 <- select(DNRJ_2018, IDADEMAE, SEXO)
label(tb2018$IDADEMAE) <- "Idade de mãe em anos completos"
label(tb2018$SEXO) <- "Gênero do nascido"
tb2018$SEXO <- factor(tb2018$SEXO, levels = c(0,1,2), labels = c("Ignorado","Masculino", "Feminino"))

tabela_2018 <- table(cut(as.numeric(tb2018$IDADEMAE), breaks = seq(0, 60, by=5), right=F), by = tb2018$SEXO)
tabela_2018 <- cbind(tabela_2018, total = rowSums(tabela_2018))
tabela_2018 <- rbind(tabela_2018, total = colSums(tabela_2018))

tab2018 <- as.data.frame.matrix(tabela_2018)
```

Porém, minha tabela sai desse jeito:

[image: tabela de contingência idade x sexo]

O r está contando um total de 1393 nascidos de mulher com 0 a 5 anos sendo que no banco de dados a mãe mais jovem tem 11 anos sendo que, no tabnet esse número está no grupo de mãe com 10 a 14 anos e no banco de dados a mãe mais jovem tem 11 anos!!

Porque isso acontece?? Porque o r não coloca as mães nas respectivas classes de idades criadas pelo cut???

Comment: Benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Para que mais pessoas possam te ajudar, é necessário desenvolver um código reproduzível. Para isso, utilize a função `dput(head(DNRJ_2018, 20))` para que possa ser possível utilizar parte de seus dados.

Comment: Como procedimento para reprodução, sugiro não utilizar `file.choose()`, porque a seleção do arquivo será manual, prefira definir o nome do arquivo e caminho para importação.

Answer (score 1):

Não pode transformar um `"factor"` em numérico diretamente, tem de primeiro transformar em `"character"`.

```
tb2018$IDADEMAE <- as.numeric(as.character(tb2018$IDADEMAE))
```

Isto é essencialmente uma pergunta duplicada de

[Transformar factor em numerico R](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/304469/transformar-factor-em-numerico-r)